# Removing underline from hyperlink in android XML

Tags: android, xml

This is what I am using to display hyperlinks in my android App.

```
<string name="Name"><a href="MY LINK">Name</a></string>
```

I want to remove the underline that is displayed in the hyperlink. I am looking   for XML code to modify the same(Not java).Thanks in advance

Comment: <string name="Name"><a href="MY LINK">Name</a></string>
is there anything i can change in this syntax to remove the underline in my hyperlink

Comment: Assuming you set the text in TextViews: In strings: `<a href="http://www.example.com/" style="text-decoration: none;">Example</a>`. And then in Java: `myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(R.string.my_hyperlink));`.

Comment: @KlingKlang still not working with your method :(

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. You can control from xml only hyperlink color.
Its because android use `Spannable`  for hyperlinks (and not only). Look at [Html.html#fromHtml](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String))

Process look like:

1. you set html as text to textview
2. textview convert html text to `Spannable` `CharSequance`
3. textview show `Spannable` `CharSquance`.
4. Each `Spannable` renders itself

Answer (score 0):

Forget about the `<a>` tag, simply use "setOnClickListener":

```
TextView website = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.website);
website.setText("Website");
if(!url.contains("http://") && !url.contains("https://") ) {
      url="http://"+url;
}
website.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
public void onClick(View v){
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
}
});
```